# Floating label on icon

Tags: semantic-ui

Is it possible to achieve something like facebook's notifications icon with Semantic UI? I.e. an icon with a red Label to show the number of notifications? Found [this thread](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/4961) but no answers there.

I tried this:

```
<Icon name='bell outline'>
  <Label color='red' floating>22</Label>
</Icon>
```

But the label doesn't show up (syntax is semantic-ui-react).

Answer (score 2):

With Semantic UI you can make another icon float to the right upper corner:

```
<i class="huge icons">
  <i class="puzzle icon"></i>
  <i class="top right corner add icon"></i>
</i>
```

but it does't help in case you want to display some number in the corner- for intance, the number of followers or the number of messages. If you want to achieve it you have to use your own css styling.

In my project I do it in following way:

```
<div class="ui top  dropdown item">
<i class="icon bell outline"></i>
<div id="live_message_badge_main_header" class="floating ui red label hidden" style="padding:2px 3px;top: 10px;left: 47px;">
  <span class='live_message_badge'>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Additionally, you need corresponding js which will fill the span.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Kind of a hack to use a dropdown, but it works. I'll give you a +1, but won't mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Found out that you don't even need a `<div class="ui top  dropdown item">`, just a div with `position: relative;` should do the trick.

Comment: @amaurymartiny you are right. In my case I am using it because I really have dropdown on icon click.